# can I add a github R package to a local CRAN libraries using miniCRAN

Tags: r, github

I am using `miniCRAN` to create a local repo and use it on an offline machine.
I have added the CRAN pacakges that I need and now would like to add an additional package that is only available on github (`multidplyr` from https://github.com/tidyverse/multidplyr).

However, using

```
addPackage(pkgs = "multidplyr", path = pth, type = c("source"), Rversion = "3.4",
           repos = "https://github.com/tidyverse/multidplyr")
```

gives the error

```
Warning: unable to access index for repository https://github.com/tidyverse/multidplyr/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://github.com/tidyverse/multidplyr/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
```

IS there a way to make this work. or any other solution? Should I just get the zip from github and copy as is into the src folder of the local repo?